# Graph Coloring implementation in traffic routing

Tags: greedy, fuzzy-logic, graph-coloring

I want to use greedy algorithm for traffic phase allocation in road junction . But the problem is the greedy algorithm gives me a result that colored vertices(represent routs) those have same origin route(suppose AB route is V1 vertex, AC route is V2 vertex here both have origin A)   some times colored in different color .But in a origin of route , it is not possible to give permission to move some vehicle and not permit to some vehicle at a same time . How can I fix it. Suggest me other algorithm if needed.

And I also want to use fuzzy coloring concept  on traffic phasing. How can I implement it?

I by modifying the greedy algorithm . Consider the constrain that vertices that from same origin must colored in same color. But the result I find is , if there 4 origin than four color is needed to color the graph .. Which I think nothing worth to use programming.